# Calculate Brieskorn Manifold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I need show that Brieskorn Manifold is submanifold with dimension $2n-1$ and calculate specifically for $d=2$ and $n=1$

$W(d)=\lbrace (z_{0},z_{1},...,z_{n})\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}\vert$  $ z_{0}^{d}+z_{1}^{2}+...+z_{n}^{2}=0$ and $\vert z_{0}\vert^{2}+\vert z_{1}\vert^{2}+...+\vert z_{n}\vert^{2}=2\rbrace$

The second cuestion I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $W(d)$ as inverse image of the regular value of a smooth function. See [Inverse of regular value is a submanifold, Milnor's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/inverse-of-regular-value-is-a-submanifold-milnors-proof).

The second part is simply say what concrete set is

$$W(d)=\lbrace(z_{0},z_{1})\in\mathbb{C}^2\,\vert\, z_{0}^{2}+z_{1}^2=0\hbox{ and }\vert z_{0}\vert^{2}+\vert z_{1}\vert^{2}=2\rbrace.$$

Comment: I don't know if I tell more about $W(d=2)$, it must be 1-manifold on $C^{2}\cong IR^{4}$

Comment: What 1-manifold? $\Bbb R$? $S^1$? Another?

Comment: A teacher told me that is a union of two $S^{1}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101325/proof-a-2n-1-compact-manifold