# Proof a $(2n-1)$-compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I have no idea how prove that
$$\{(z_0,\ldots,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \quad| \quad z_0^d+z_1^2\ldots+z_n^2=0, \quad |z_0|^2+|z_1|^2\ldots+|z_n|^2=2\}$$ is a $(2n-1)$-compact manifold.

How give the charts. For $n=1$ and $d=2$ not distinguish which 1- manifdold is?

Comment: Many ways. One could be. Use the implicit function theorem. Divide in cases. Consider the locus where one of the (real) component is different from zero, i.e. look at the points in different hemispheres of the sphere given by the second equation.

Answer (score 4):

You do *not* want to give charts. Here are some hints to get you started.

Compactness should follow immediately from the fact that a sphere in $\Bbb R^{2n+1}$ is compact and level sets of continuous functions are closed.

In general, any time you have a set $X\subset\Bbb R^N$, say, that is defined by equations, you'd like to use those equations to define a smooth mapping $f\colon \Bbb R^N\to \Bbb R^s$ so that $X=f^{-1}(0)$. If you check that the rank of $df_x$ is $s$ for every $x\in X$, then it follows from the implicit function theorem that $X$ is an $(N-s)$-dimensional manifold. In your problem you have a mix of holomorphic and non-holomorphic, so you should either convert everything to real coordinates or, if you're familiar with doing calculus with $\partial/\partial z$ and $\partial/\partial\bar z$, you can write the functions in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(f, g):\mathbb{C^{n+1}}\to\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}$ by

$(f, g)(z_0,\ldots, z_n)=(f(z_0,\ldots, z_n), g(z_0,\ldots, z_n))=(z_0^d+z_1^2\ldots+z_n^2, |z_0|^2+|z_1|^2\ldots+|z_n|^2)$

then $(0, 2)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}$ is a regular value, $f$ is holomorphic and the jacobian $J$ have rank 3 on $\mathbb{C}$.

Therefore $(f, g)^{-1}(0, 2)$ is a $2n-1$ manifold, (Brieskorn Manifold).

Comment: Could you please give more details about "(0,2) is a regular value"?

Comment: How do we know the Jacobian has rank $3$?