# The inverse image of any regular value is a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:M^m\subset\mathbb R^k\to N^n$ be a smooth map between manifolds with $m>n$. Let $y\in N$ be a regular value for $f$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ and $L:\mathbb R^k\to\mathbb R^{m-n}$ be a linear map, non-singular on $R=\ker (df_x)$.

How can we see that the image of $f^{-1}(y)$ under $F=(f,L):M\to N\times\mathbb R^{m-n}$ is $y\times\mathbb R^{m-n}$?

$F$ is a diffeomorphism between a neighborhood $U\ni x$ and $V\ni y$. Can we see that $F$ is a diffeomorphism between $f^{-1}(y)\cap U$ and $y\times\mathbb R^{m-n}\cap V$?

Concluding that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a manifold follows.

([This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/inverse-of-regular-value-is-a-submanifold-milnors-proof) adresses the first of the above issues but the answer is not convincing.)

Comment: We can't, right? What happens if M is compact, for instance.